# Automatically tangle org files in a specific directory

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm converting my dotfiles to org-babel files because I really enjoyed rewriting my Emacs configuration in it, and I have a function for the `init.org` that automatically tangles it whenever I save. However, I haven't been successful in making the `.org` files in say `~/.dotfiles` to do the same automatically. I have this function currently:

```
(defun my/tangle-dotfiles ()
  "If the current file is in '~/.dotfiles', the code blocks are tangled"
  (when (equal (buffer-file-name)
               (expand-file-name "~/.dotfiles/tmux.org"))
    (org-babel-tangle)
    (message "Dotfile tangled")))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'my/tangle-dotfiles)
```

However, this only works for the specific file I name, not for any org file. Using `*.org` doesn't work either, nor have I figured out how to extract the directory name from both the buffer and directory and do it that way.

I also asked on the #emacs on Freenode but nobody answered me there. Any help or pointer on where to begin would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I figured out how to do it:

```
(defun my/tangle-dotfiles ()
  "If the current file is in '~/.dotfiles', the code blocks are tangled"
  (when (equal (file-name-directory (directory-file-name buffer-file-name))
               (concat (getenv "HOME") "/.dotfiles/"))
    (org-babel-tangle)
    (message "%s tangled" buffer-file-name)))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'my/tangle-dotfiles)
```